# Filling Lists/ Tables by reading input files

Tags: python, arrays, list, data-structures

I am kind of new to data structure and I am having some trouble extracting specific information from multiple .txt files. I want to group specific information from junk input files.

The files are formatted as following :

```
---------------------------------------------------
Block 1
---------------------------------------------------
Block 2
---------------------------------------------------
Block 3
---------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
```

A random .txt file that serves as the input (parsed.txt) looks something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------
    Timestamp: 1453939200(2016-01-28 01:00:00)
    Peer AS Number: 37989
    Local AS Number: 12654
    Peer IP Address: 203.123.48.6
    Local IP Address: 193.0.4.28
---------------------------------------------------
    Timestamp: 1453939200(2016-01-28 01:00:00)
    Peer AS Number: 1836
    Local AS Number: 12654
    Peer IP Address: 146.228.1.3
    Local IP Address: 193.0.4.28
---------------------------------------------------
    Timestamp: 1453939200(2016-01-28 01:00:00)
    Peer AS Number: 1836
    Local AS Number: 12654
    Peer IP Address: 146.228.1.3
    Local IP Address: 193.0.4.28
---------------------------------------------------
    Timestamp: 1453939200(2016-01-28 01:00:00)
    Peer AS Number: 1836
    Local AS Number: 12654
    Peer IP Address: 2a01:2a8::3
    Local IP Address: 2001:67c:2e8:2:ffff:0:4:28
```

Required:

The main field in each block is the "Local AS Number". I would like to read each block, check the "Local AS Number" and update some sort of data structure such that :

- If is new, Create a (Table, List,... ) with it as its name containing
  the 3 other fields as columns (column name would be the field's
  respective name), and fill the fields with the respective value.
- If the "Local AS Number" has been read in previous blocks, then just
  fill the other fields of the existing table.

The result should looks something like this :

```
                                                AS 12654
Timestamp               Peer AS Number              Peer IP Address              Local IP Address
1453939200              1836                            146.228.1.3                 193.0.4.28
1453939200              1836                            146.228.1.3                 193.0.4.28
1453939200              1836                            2a01:2a8::3                 2001:67c:2e8:2:ffff:0:4:28
```

I tried some string manipulation, but it turned out to be a complete mess, so I figured there should be a data structure more suitable.
Please note that the Tables must be active to be updated until the last .txt file has been parsed. This is a problem that I absolutely do not have an idea even where to begin solving it.

Comment: HINT: Dictionary of lists is the answer to your troubles. Once I get time later tonight, and if no one has answered this satisfactorily, I'll write up a detailed answer. Also, well written question!

Comment: I will check Dictionaries out and try to come with a solution, but I am also looking forward to your answer !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AxxE suggested, a dictionary of lists of tuples does what you want. Each list contains all the blocks for a given local AS number stored in tuples.

I use the re module to extract the numbers from each line collecting each block's data into a tuple which is added to a list that is keyed by the local AS number in the dictionary. Error checks might be added, of course.

```
import re
import fileinput
records = {}
file = open('parsed.txt', 'r')
in_line = file.readline()
while in_line:
    time_stamp = re.search(r': (\d+)\(',file.readline()).group(1)
    peer_AS = re.search(r': (\d+)',file.readline()).group(1)
    local_AS = re.search(r' \d+',file.readline()).group(0)
    peer_IP = re.search(r': (.+)$',file.readline()).group(1)
    local_IP = re.search(r': (.+)$',file.readline()).group(0)
    if local_AS in records:
        records[local_AS].append((time_stamp, peer_AS, peer_IP, local_IP))
    else:
        records[local_AS] = [(time_stamp, peer_AS, peer_IP, local_IP)]
    in_line = file.readline()
file.close()
```

The `records` may now be printed out as you indicated.

```
for i in records:
    entry = records[i]
    print('\t\t\tLocal AS Number: {}'.format(i))
    print('Timestamp\tPeer AS Number\tPeer IP Address\t\tLocal IP Address')
    for item in entry:
        print('{}\t{}\t\t{}\t\t{}'.format(item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3]))
```

This yields the output, below. I extended the example file changing the local AS number to a different one just to show the idea.

```
                  Local AS Number 12654
Timestamp   Peer AS Number  Peer IP Address     Local IP Address
1453939200  37989       203.123.48.6        193.0.4.28
1453939200  1836        146.228.1.3         193.0.4.28
1453939200  1836        146.228.1.3         193.0.4.28
1453939200  1836        2a01:2a8::3         2001:67c:2e8:2:ffff:0:4:28 
                  Local AS Number 12655
Timestamp   Peer AS Number  Peer IP Address     Local IP Address
1453939200  37989       203.123.48.6        193.0.4.28
1453939200  1836        146.228.1.3         193.0.4.28
1453939200  1836        146.228.1.3         193.0.4.28
1453939200  1836        2a01:2a8::3         2001:67c:2e8:2:ffff:0:4:28
```